# Syntax in html to autoplay .mp3 files with a loop automatically

Tags: html, syntax

What is the syntax in html to autoplay ".mp3" files with a loop; automatically when start the web page? 
I tried with this syntax;

```
<audio control loop autoplay>
<source src= "music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

this syntax only loop the audio. it will not start the audio automatically

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try the basic thing to get your need,

```
   <audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="yoursource.mp3">
</audio>
```

thanx to [Autoplay an audio with HTML5 embed tag while the player is invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179190/autoplay-an-audio-with-html5-embed-tag-while-the-player-is-invisible)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a small bit of javascript to auto-play it. Warning: Playing this snippet may be annoying!

```js
var src = "https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/horse.ogg";

function loadaudio(src) {
  var myaudio = document.getElementById("horse");
  myaudio.autoplay = true;
  myaudio.load(src);
};
```

```html
<body onload="loadaudio();">
<audio id="horse" controls loop>
<source src= "https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
</body>
```

Comment: if you added an id to the source attribute, you could set the src via javascript.. i didn't but you get the gist